# Reactjs state update after localstorage data changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the user inside localstorage, when user logouts the localstorage data becomes NULL. When user logins, the localstorages fills with user's data but to check this my userEffect in App.js do not reflect any change.

i have signUp

```
  dispatch(signin(form, history));
  history.push("/");                    //go back to App.js file
```

in Navbar the user data changes

```
  const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"))); 

 const logout = () => {
 dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
 dispatch({
  type: "EMPTY_CART",
  });
    history.push("/");
    setUser(null);
  };
```

now at App.js i have

```
 const user = JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem("profile"));
 const getCartItems = useCallback(async () => {
 if (user) {
   console.log("Yes user exixts");
   dispatch(getEachUserCart(user?.result?._id));
  } else {
   console.log("No user exist");
  }
}, []); //

useEffect(() => {
  getCartItems();
}, [getCartItems]);
```

Now if u look above, after dispatching signUp action, i come back to App.js but here the useEffect don't run nor it checks if user have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey – looks like you have a missing dependency issue. You need to have it like so

```
const getCartItems = useCallback(async () => {
 if (user) {
   console.log("Yes user exixts");
   dispatch(getEachUserCart(user?.result?._id));
  } else {
   console.log("No user exist");
  }
}, [user]);
```

Otherwise, this function will never be redeclared with the latest user value. Kindly let me know if that helps

Comment: Ah – let me run it locally to see what's up!

Comment: Renders correctly on my side, one thing I don't have is the dispatch to `getEachUserCart` so maybe there's an issue with that action? Does it mutate the user object somehow?